# Converting Ragged Tensor to List

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, tensorflow2.0

So I was trying to convert ragged tensor to list. The ragged tensor is returned as a result of tokenization of texts using [sub_word Tokenizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/guide/subwords_tokenizer).
I am trying to convert this ragged tensor to list using the following code:

```
token = tokenizer.pt.tokenize(text) # returns ragged tensor
token_as_list = token.to_list()
```

But this results in error :

> ValueError: to_list can only be used in eager mode.

I checked if i was running in eager environment using `tf.executing_eagerly()` which return `True`

Are  there any other methods to convert ragged tensor to list.
I want to do it because i want to increase and pad the last dimension for eg:

```
tensor = (64,120) # (batch_size,seq_len)
# convert this to (64,128) by padding it
```

Comment: Hi @Shivam Singh, Please make sure that you have installed the same version of  `Tensorflow` and `Tensorflow_text` in your system. What is the `.pt` symbolized in the code? Please refer this similar code mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/guide/subwords_tokenizer#build_the_tokenizer) which might help you to convert ragged tensor to list.

Comment: @TFer2 tokenizer contains 2 modules one for english which is `.en` and one for portugese which is `.pt`. I did refer to the code but it still gives me the same error. I also checked and confirmed that i am executing my code in eager environment.

Comment: I have the supported version of `tensorflow_text` installed with my `tensorflow`

Comment: Okay, Could you please share minimal reproducible code to understand the issue and to replicate the error.

Comment: The error could be [Reproduced Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1i7AmLnDGgVnK1w8pv2ErPaoz9MuhHJfC?usp=sharing)